# Confused about Virtualization and Hypervisors available for Debian 10: QEMU, KVM, Xen, LXC, Bhyve, Virtuozzo - What are they? How do they work?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine

I used to use Virtualbox to manage virtual machines, but this has been removed from the Debian packages. (Fine with me, it wasn't particularly well suited for use with servers as far as I remember.)

I did some research for a replacement a while ago and there doesn't seem to be any.

I managed to follow a tutorial (I will put the link here if I can find it again, it was some while ago) which instructed me to install some packages, one of which gives me a command line tool `virt-manager`.

I recently realized that this isn't actually a virtual machine at all, it is just a UI for some kind of server which runs in the background somewhere and gives me access to different types of hypervisors - QEMU/KVM, Xen, LXC, Bhyve, Virtuozzo and "QEMU/KVM user session" - the UI calls them "connections".

This point must have evaded me previously. By the way sorry if I don't use quite the correct terminology, I'm rather confused about the whole thing.

What is the difference between all these different types of "connections". What exactly is each of them and how do they all differ? Are some suitable for particular use cases or are they all basically a different implementation of the same thing? Finally if anyone can recommend some reference (website, youtube link, etc) that I can read/watch to get an overview of this stuff I'd be glad to recieve it.

## Further stuff I found

Brief overview of KVM, QEMU and libvirt

- https://www.thegeekyway.com/kvm-vs-qemu-vs-libvirt/

Comment: We don't need a separate tag for hypervisor. [tag:virtualization] is a synonym of [tag:virtual-machine], so there's no reason for hypervisor to be a separate tag.

Comment: @muru Are these three all the same thing? Virtualization is a technology, virtual-machines are instances of a software (the machine) which is executed using virtualization technology, an a hypervisor is the software which controls or manages the execution of a collection of software (a virtual machine).

Comment: They don't have to be the same thing. They just have to be close enough for people who are interested in the topic to be able to filter and follow it. Not every *thing* needs to have its own tag.